# Scale cropped image to screen width

Tags: html, css

I can crop an image using

```html
<img
 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg/800px-Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg" 

 style="width: 200px; height: 200px; object-fit: none; object-position: -350px -300px">
```

How can I now scale the image to the (unknown) width of an enclosing container?

Comment: What do you want to happen if a) the height of the container is not enough to show the full cropped image and b) if the height of the container is a lot bigger than is needed to show the cropped image

Answer (score 0):

You can use view height(vh) and view width(vw) instead of static pixels, so that the picture will have the same size on whatever screen you open it.

Comment: That will not preserve the crop

Answer (score 0):

We know that when the container is 200px wide that the image has to be moved by -365px and -300px.

We also know (by inspection) that the natural width and height of the img (which are what are used by default in the code given in the question) is 800px by 1000px.

This snippet sets these measurements as CSS variables.

It then uses a div instead of an img (as replaced elements cannot have pseudo after elements), gives it the scaled width and height of the square cropped image and an after pseudo element which has the whole image as background and is then translated to the correct position.

```css
.container {
  width: 25vw; /* could be anything */
  height: 30vh;
}
.croppedimg {
  /* these all in the same units (px was used in the question) */
  --originalW: 800; /* the natural (original) width of the img */
  --originalH: 1000; /* ditto height */
  --cutoutLeft: -365; /* amount needed to move left to crop */
  --cutoutTop: -300; /* amount needed to move top to crop */
  --cutout: 200; /* length of side of the square */

  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* this gives us a square */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.croppedimg::after {
  content: '';
  /* has same aspect ratio as the original image */
  width: calc((var(--originalW) / var(--cutout)) * 100%);
  height:  calc((var(--originalH) / var(--cutout)) * 100%);
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg/800px-Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  transform: translateX(calc((-365 / 800) * 100%)) translateY(calc((-300 / 1000) * 100%)); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="croppedimg"></div>
</div>
```